# ¿Cual validación es correcta y porque? BOOLEAN; VOID

Tags: java, eclipse, while

Tengo una duda sobre como validar correctamente.
Tengo 2 formas de realizarlo y no se como es de manera ideal

Con una funcion booleana:

```
    public static boolean Validar_juego (String juego) {

    boolean valido = false; 
            while (!juego.equals(ruleta) && !juego.equals(blackJack) && !juego.equals(poker)) {
                valido = false;
                System.out.println(msj_juego_incorrecto);
                juego = input.nextLine();
            }
            valido = true;
        return valido;              
    }
```

O con una función de tipo VOID:

```
    public static void Validar_juego (String juego) {

            while (!juego.equals(ruleta) && !juego.equals(blackJack) && !juego.equals(poker)) {
                System.out.println(msj_juego_incorrecto);
                juego = input.nextLine();
            }
    }
```

Que diferencia hay y cual sería la validación correcta?
Gracias!!

Comment: La primera de las opciones la verdad no entiendo de que sirve el while si sea lo que sea de todas formas antes de retornar el valor asigna un true a la variable valido... Más allá de que temas dos maneras sería bueno que las pruebes ya que no importa la circunstancia, la primera opción siempre devuelve true.

Answer (score 1):

Ninguna de las dos formas es correcta o incorrecta sino que dependerá de la finalidad que le quieras dar a ese método  `Validar_juego(String juego)` .

Si solamente vas a necesitar realizar  esta asignación `juego = input.nextLine();` , con el método que devuelve void sería suficiente ya que no necesitas que este devuelva un booleano para que realice esa acción de asignación.

Si, por algún motivo,vos deseas que ademas de esa asignación el método devuelva true o false porque lo estas invocando desde otro lugar el cual necesita información para realizar alguna acción, ahí si podrías indicarle que retorne boolean.